# Javascript: how to access form object's fields

Tags: javascript, forms

According to my understanding `this.form` sends the whole form object. I have this form

```
<form name ="bannerForm" method="post">
 <table>
     <tr>
         <td>Enter banner message</td>
         <td><input class="messagebannner" type="text" id="bannerMessage" name="bannerMessage" size="40" onblur="validateEmptyFields(this);"></td>
         <td><span name="messageBanner" id="messageBanner"></span></td>
     </tr>
```

And i want to dynamically change the value of the span tag and i am trying to do it without hardcoding the id in the validateEmptyField() function. How can I achieve this? is it really possible? can the form object be helpfull in this regard??
this is validateEmptyField() function:

```
function validateEmptyFields(inputField){
     if(inputField.value.length === 0){

//show error message in span
         return false
     }
    else {
     return true;
}
}
```

Comment: What value are you trying to inject into the `<span>`?

Comment: I just want to show some text

Comment: Additionally: Why your span has a name?

Comment: Good catch, @Fuzzyma. It's a display element and shouldn't have a name for form submission.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the form and the form fields like this.

```
//form acccess
document.forms["my_form_name"];
//fields access
document.forms["my_form_name"]["input_name"];
```

Comment: Where the name is a valid identifier, dot properties can also be used, for example the above can be: `var form = document.forms.my_form_name` and `form.input_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of form validation needs some improvement.

Check out [this W3Schools page on JavaScript form validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp). It's pretty easy once you get the concept of it.

Your HTML and JavaScript should look something like the following after you adjust it a little bit.

HTML:

```
<form id="bannerForm" name="bannerForm" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter banner message</td>
            <td>
                <input class="messagebannner" type="text"
                    name="bannerMessage" size="40" onblur="validateBannerForm();" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="messageBanner"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateBannerForm() {
    var x = document.forms["bannerForm"]["bannerMessage"];
    if (x.value == null || x.value == "") {
        document.forms["bannerForm"]["messageBanner"].value = "This is an error message.";
        return false;
    }
}
```

I personally do not like this method of validation at all, but it's simple to understand and seems to suit your purposes. I would research other validation practices when it comes to JavaScript and HTML forms.

Comment: The test `x.value == null` will never be true since the value of a form control is always returned as a string, and any string (including an empty string) does not equal *null*. Please don't reference w3Schools, the code there is awful, the MDN [Data form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) article is much better.

Answer (score -1):

You can do some jQuery magic (also doable without but easier)

```
$(inputField).parent().next().children('span').text(your text here);
```

Comment: I don't see anything in this question related to jQuery, but this does work.

Comment: Well - you can do it without. But i wasnt in the mood to write it^^

Comment: I want to do that via javascript

Comment: Well then you have to do it the old way nut I think you may figure it out yourself. Anyway: why down vote me? This answer is not wrong!